# Problems running powershell script with php exec

Tags: php, windows, iis, powershell, exec

i have troubles with running valid powershell script (tested from cmd). I want the script to test if user exists on office 365 but authentication just wont pass via php while it executes normal in cmd.

Server is windows 2008 R2, IIS 7.5, PHP 5.4 NTS.

I'm in general linux user and I have troubles getting this MS thing to work big time so any suggestion is really appreciated.

here is my powershell script:

```
$username = "adminuser@my_domain"
$password = "password"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

Import-Module MSOnline -force
Connect-Msolservice -Credential $cred

Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName student@my_domain
```

and php part:

```
exec("powershell -Command C:/inetpub/wwwroot/office365/test.ps1 < NUL", $output);
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

output result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Connect-MsolService : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automa
    [1] => tion.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown.
    [2] => At C:\inetpub\wwwroot\office365\test.ps1:8 char:20
    [3] => + Connect-Msolservice <<<<  -Credential $cred
    [4] =>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Mic
    [5] =>    rosoftOnlineException
    [6] =>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x80070002,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Autom
    [7] =>    ation.ConnectMsolService
    [8] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix.

try:

Copy the folders called `MSOnline` and `MSOnline Extended` from the source

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

to the folder

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

And then in PS run the Import-Module MSOnline, and it will automatically get the module :D